# MySQL Query AND IN (select.... - Need assistance in clarifying and is it a Sub Routine

Tags: php, mysql, subroutine

Can you let me know if my interpretation is correct (the last AND part)?

```
$q = "SELECT title,name,company,address1,address2 
      FROM registrations 
      WHERE title != 0 AND id IN (
          SELECT registrar_id 
          FROM registrations_industry 
          WHERE industry_id = '$industryid'
      )";
```

Below was really where I am not sure:

```
... AND id IN (select registrar_id from registrations_industry where industry_id='$industryid')
```

**Interpretation:**  Get any match on id(registrations id field) equals registrar_id(field) from the join table registrations_industry where industry_id equals the set $industryid

**Is this select statement considered a sub routine since it's a query within the main query?**

So an example would be with the register table id search to 23 would look like:

**registrations**(table)

```
id=23,title=owner,name=mike,company=nono,address1=1234 s walker lane,address2
```

**registrations_industry**(table)

```
id=256, registrar_id=23, industry_id=400<br>
id=159, registrar_id=23, industry_id=284<br>
id=227, registrar_id=23, industry_id=357
```

I assume this would return 3 records with the same registration table data And of course varying registrations_industry returns.

Comment: These two pages should be helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html  It's a subquery which is basically a JOIN

Comment: as your select only use one table "registrations", and that table contains only one row, you can get max one row in result, if you want more rows you may want to use a join insted for a subquery

Comment: Your interpretation seems right, but your example seems wrong.  In your example, the subquery would return only a single row, since you're specifying an `industry_id` and none of the example rows share `industry_id`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given test data set your query will return one record. This one:
`id=23,title=owner,name=mike,company=nono,address1=1234 s walker lane,address2`
To get three records with the same registration table data and varying registrations_industry you need to use `JOIN`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT r.title, r.name, r.company, r.address1, r.address2 
FROM registrations AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations_industry AS ri
ON ri.registrar_id=r.id
WHERE r.title!=0 AND ri.industry_id={$industry_id}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the essay, I didn't realize it was as long as it is until looking at it now.  And although you've checked an answer, I hope you read this gain some insight into why this solution is preferred and how it evolved out of your original query.

### First things first

Your query

```
$q = "SELECT title,name,company,address1,address2 
      FROM registrations 
      WHERE title != 0 AND id IN (
          SELECT registrar_id 
          FROM registrations_industry 
          WHERE industry_id = '$industryid'
      )";
```

seems fine.  The `IN` syntax is equivalent to a number of `OR` matches.  For example

```
WHERE field_id IN (101,102,103,105)
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
WHERE (field_id = 101 
    OR field_id = 102
    OR field_id = 103
    OR field_id = 105)
```

You complicate it a bit by introducing a subquery, no problem.  As long as your subquery returns one column (and yours does), passing it to `IN` will be fine.

In your case, you're comparing `registrations.id` to `registrations_industry.registrar_id`.  (Note: This is just `<table>.<field>` syntax, nothing special, but helpful to disambiguate what tables your fields are in.)

This seems fine.

## What happens

SQL would first run the subquery, generating a result set of `registrar_id`s where the `industry_id` was set as specified.

SQL would then run the outer query, replacing the subquery with its results and you would get rows from `registrations` where `registrations.id` matched one of the `registrar_id`s returned from the subquery.

Subqueries are helpful to debug your code, because you can pull out the subquery and run it separately, ensuring its output is as you expect.

## Optimization

While subqueries are good for debugging, they're slow, at least slower than using optmized `JOIN` statements.

And in this case, you can convert your query to a single-level query (without subqueries) by using a `JOIN`.

First, you'd start with basically the exact same outer query:

```
SELECT title,name,company,address1,address2 
FROM registrations 
WHERE title != 0 AND ...
```

But you're also interested in data from the `registrations_industry` table, so you need to include that.  Giving us

```
SELECT title,name,company,address1,address2 
FROM registrations, registrations_industry 
WHERE title != 0 AND ...
```

We need to fix the ... and now that we have the `registrations_industry` table we can:

```
SELECT title,name,company,address1,address2 
FROM registrations, registrations_industry 
WHERE title != 0 
AND id = registrar_id
AND industry_id = '$industryid'
```

Now a problem might arise if both tables have an `id` column -- since just saying `id` is ambiguous.  We can disambiguate this by using the `<table>.<field>` syntax.  As in

```
SELECT registrations.title, registrations.name,
    registrations.company, registrations.address1, registrations.address2 
FROM registrations, registrations_industry 
WHERE registrations.title != 0 
AND registrations_industry.industry_id = '$industryid'
```

We didn't have to use this syntax for all the field references, but we chose to for clarity.  The query now is unnecessarily complex because of all the table names.  We can shorten them while still providing disambiguation and clarity.  We do this by creating table aliases.

```
SELECT r.title, r.name, r.company, r.address1, r.address2 
FROM registrations r, registrations_industry ri
WHERE r.title != 0 
AND ri.industry_id = '$industryid'
```

By placing `r` and `ri` after the two tables in the `FROM` clause, we're able to refer to them using these shortcuts.  This cleans up the query but still gives us the ability to clearly specify which tables the fields are coming from.

***Sidenote:*** We could be more explicit about the table aliases by including the optional `AS` e.g. `FROM registrations`**`AS`**`r` rather than just `FROM registrations r`, but I typically reserve `AS` for field aliases.

If you run the query now you will get what is called a "Cartesian product" or in SQL lingo, a `CROSS JOIN`.  This is because we didn't define any relationship between the two tables when, in fact, there is one.  To fix this we need to reintroduce part of the original query that was lost: the relationship between the two tables

```
r.id = ri.registrar_id
```

so that our query now looks like

```
SELECT r.title, r.name, r.company, r.address1, r.address2 
FROM registrations r, registrations_industry ri
WHERE r.title != 0 
AND r.id = ri.registrar_id
AND ri.industry_id = '$industryid'
```

And this should work perfectly.

## Nitpicking -- implicit vs. explicit joins

But the nitpicker in me needs to point out that this is called an "implicit join".  Basically you're joining tables but not using the `JOIN` syntax.

A simpler example of an implicit join is

```
SELECT *
FROM foo f, bar b
WHERE f.id = b.foo_id
```

The corresponding *explicit* syntax is

```
SELECT *
FROM foo f
JOIN bar b ON f.id = b.foo_id
```

The result will be identical but it is using proper (and clearer) syntax.  (Its clearer because it explicitly stats that there is a relationship between the `foo` and `bar` tables and it is defined by `f.id = b.foo_id`.)

We could similarly express your ***implicit*** query

```
SELECT r.title, r.name, r.company, r.address1, r.address2 
FROM registrations r, registrations_industry ri
WHERE r.title != 0 
AND r.id = ri.registrar_id
AND ri.industry_id = '$industryid'
```

***explicitly*** as follows

```
SELECT r.title, r.name, r.company, r.address1, r.address2 
FROM registrations r
JOIN registrations_industry ri ON r.id = ri.registrar_id
WHERE r.title != 0 
AND ri.industry_id = '$industryid'
```

As you can see, the relationship between the tables is now in the `JOIN` clause, so that the `WHERE` and subsequent `AND` and `OR` clauses are free to express any restrictions.  Another way to look at this is if you took out the `WHERE + AND/OR` clauses, the relationship between tables would still hold and the results would still "make sense" whereas if you used the implicit method and removed the `WHERE + AND/OR` clauses, your result set would contain rows that were misleading.

Lastly, the `JOIN` syntax by itself will cause rows that are in `registrations`, but do not have any corresponding rows in `registrations_industry` to not be returned.

Depending on your use case, you may want rows from `registrations` to appear in the results even if there are no corresponding entries in `registrations_industry`.  To do this you would use what's called an `OUTER JOIN`.  In this case, we want what is called a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because we want all of the rows of the table on the left (`registrations`).  We could have alternatively used `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` for the right table or simply `OUTER JOIN` for the outer join of *both* tables.

Therefore our query becomes

```
SELECT r.title, r.name, r.company, r.address1, r.address2 
FROM registrations r
LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations_industry ri ON r.id = ri.registrar_id
WHERE r.title != 0 
AND ri.industry_id = '$industryid'
```

And we're done.

The end result is we have a query that is

- faster in terms of runtime
- more compact / concise
- more explicit about what tables the fields are coming from
- more explicit about the relationship between the tables

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of this query would be:

```
SELECT title,  name, company, address1, address2
  FROM registrations, registrations_industry
 WHERE title != 0
   AND id = registrar_id
   AND industry_id = '$industryid'
```

Your version was a subquery, this version is a simple join. Your assumptions about your query are generally correct, but it is harder for SQL to optimize and a little harder to unravel to anyone trying to read the code. Also, you won't be able to extract the data from the registrations_industry table in that parent SELECT statement because it's not technically joining and the subtable is not a part of the parent query.

Comment: Certainly, explicit joins are preferred.